# Issue with join: Error converting data type nvarchar to float?

Tags: sql-server

I've been trying to run the program below and I keep on getting the error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float

SQL:

```
SELECT 
   distinct 
    coalesce(a.File_NBR,b.File_NBR) as ID,
    b.Division,
    b.Program,
    a.Full_Name,
    a.SBC_RESULT
FROM 
    New_EEs.dbo.vw_SBC_RESULTS a
full join 
    New_EEs.dbo.vw_SBC_Employee_Info b on a.File_NBR = b.File_NBR
where 
    (a.File_NBR is not null OR b.File_NBR is not null)
    and A.Full_Name is not null 
order by 
    a.Full_Name, b.Division,  b.Program
```

When I comment out    /***and  A.Full_Name is not null ***/ the program works.

I can't figure out what the error means and why the join works when I comment out  /***and  A.Full_Name is not null ***/

Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try lower case "a" a.Full_Name

Comment: Are the data types for File_NBR different between the base tables involved in the join?

Comment: hi. I just changed to a lower case a still did not work. Yes, The data types for File_NBR may be different, how would I write for that - I'm new to SQL server

Comment: You need to use CAST or CONVERT on either a.File_NBR or b.File_NBR. Also `A.Full_Name is not null` in your where clause is converting your `FULL OUTER JOIN` into a `LEFT JOIN`. Perhaps you should put that in your `JOIN ` or change the `where`  to `AND (A.Full_Name is not null or a.File_NBR is null)`

Comment: Hi conrad-frix. Thanks would you mind giving me a quick example? Thanks!

Comment: @user2270911 you can fine several in the MSDN Docs [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: b.file_nbr is (float,not null) data type and a. file_nbr is (in, not null)

Comment: Which type is `a.file_nbr`? `in` isn't a type.

Comment: sory its (int, not null)

Comment: Oh well, I was thinking it may have been a value that wouldn't convert properly to a `FLOAT`. Still, the only conversion going on appears to be the int-to-float, so you may want to try casting `a.file_nbr` to a float in the `SELECT` and the `JOIN`. In the `SELECT`, instead of `coalesce(a.File_NBR,b.File_NBR) as ID` try `coalesce(cast(a.File_NBR as float,b.File_NBR) as ID`, and in the join try `on cast(a.File_NBR as float) = b.File_NBR`. That's all I can think of - good luck!

Comment: Still getting the error :( SELECT 
--distinct 
coalesce(cast(a.File_NBR as float), b.File_NBR)as ID,
       b.Division,
    b.Program,
       a.Full_Name,
       a.SBC_RESULT
  FROM New_EEs.dbo.vw_SBC_RESULTS a
 left join New_EEs.dbo.vw_SBC_Employee_Info b
  on cast(a.File_NBR as float) = b.File_NBR
    --where  (A.Full_Name is not null or a.File_NBR is null)
     --and  a.Full_Name is not null 
order by a.Full_Name, b.Division,  b.Program;

Comment: And everything works good if you just do: `SELECT * FROM New_EEs.dbo.vw_SBC_RESULTS`?, no filters

Comment: so this worked: I changed both columns to char.  
SELECT 
coalesce((cast(a.File_NBR AS char(8))), cast(b.File_NBR AS char(8)))as ID,
       b.Division,
    b.Program,
       a.Full_Name,
       a.SBC_RESULT
  FROM New_EEs.dbo.vw_SBC_RESULTS a
 left join New_EEs.dbo.vw_SBC_Employee_Info b
  on cast(a.File_NBR AS char(8)) =  cast(b.File_NBR AS char(8))
order by a.Full_Name, b.Division,  b.Program;

Comment: @user2270911 please see the example i posted.

Answer (score 4):

The error message clearly says that the issue has to do with conversion of an `nvarchar` to a `float`. There's no explicit conversion in your query, therefore it's about implicit one. If the issue indeed stems from this particular query and not from somewhere else, only two places can be responsible for that:

1) the join predicate;

2) the COALESCE call.

Both places involve one and the same pair of columns, `a.File_NBR` and `b.File_NBR`. So, one of them *must* be an `nvarchar` column and the other a `float` one. Since the `float` type has higher precedence than `nvarchar`, the latter would implicitly be converted to the former, not the other way around. And apparently one of the string values failed to convert. That's the explanation of the immediate issue (the conversion).

I've seen your comment where you are saying that one of the columns is an `int` and the other `float`. I have no problem with that as I believe you are talking about columns in physical tables whereas both sources in this query appear to be views, judging by their names. I believe one of the columns enjoys a transformation to `nvarchar` in a view, and this query ends up seeing it as such. So, that should account for you where the `nvarchar` can come from.

As for an explanation to why commenting a seemingly irrelevant condition out appears to make such a big difference, the answer must lie in the internals of the query planner's workings. While there's a [documented order of *logical* evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) of clauses in a Transact-SQL SELECT query, the real, *physical* order may differ from that. The actual plan chosen for the query determines that physical order. And the choice of a plan can be affected, in particular, by such a trivial thing as incorporation or elimination of a simple condition.

To apply that to your situation, when the offending condition is commented out, the planner chooses such a plan for the query that both the join predicate and the COALESCE expression evaluate only when all the rows capable of causing the issue in question have been filtered out by predicates in the underlying views. When the condition is put back, however, the query is assigned a different execution plan, and either COALESCE or (more likely) the join predicate ends up being applied to a row containing a string that cannot be converted to a float, which results in an exception raised.

Conversion of both `a.File_NBR`  and `b.File_NBR` to `char`, as you did, is one way of solving the issue. You could in fact pick any of these four string types:

- `char`
- `varchar`
- `nchar`
- `nvarchar`

And since one of the columns is already a string (possibly the `a.File_NBR` one, but you are at a better position to find that out exactly), the conversion could be applied to the other one only.

Alternatively, you could look into the view producing the `nvarchar` column to try and see if the `int` to `nvarchar` conversion could be eliminated in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f497/2), maybe will be useful.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
ID FLOAT)

INSERT INTO TEST(ID) VALUES(NULL)
INSERT INTO TEST(ID) VALUES(12.3)

--SELECT COALESCE(ID,'TEST') FROM TEST; NOT WORKING ERROR:Error converting data type nvarchar to float
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(ID AS VARCHAR),'TEST') FROM TEST; --WORKS
```